# How can I set up React and Flask on the same host but different paths?

Tags: apache, reactjs, flask, routes

I have a react application which uses react-router and redux that I have been developing on the react-dev-server through localhost:3000. It interfaces with an Flask backend that was developed on the Flask server through localhost:5000 and is specifically meant to handle API calls and various back-end automation tasks.

What I'd like to do is move both of these servers onto Apache utilizing the same hostname where Flask would handle all requests to `myhostname.com/api/v1/{request}` and React would handle everything else.

I believe this is possible but am not sure how to approach it. I know I could just bundle my React application up and have it be served through Flask, a great solution to that situation is found here [Flask and React routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620276/flask-and-react-routing), however I would like these components to remain physically separate from each other if possible.

I can run both the front-end and back-end independently through Apache without issue, but when ran together, all requests get handled by React for some reason.

Not sure if this is really the best approach in general, open to suggestions to a better way to implement something like this. But I assume the solution is going lie in Apache. I just have yet to figure out how to direct traffic a bit more specifically for me.

React catches the request to the /api and redirects it from this block here that I'm borrowing.

```
@connect(store => {
    return { user: store.user }
})
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const { user, component, ...rest } = this.props;

        return (
            <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                user.isAuthenticated 
                ? React.createElement(component, props)
                : (<Redirect to={{
                       pathname: '/login', 
                       state: { from: props.location }}}/>)
            )}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: so youre saying you dont want flask to serve your react app as static assets?

Comment: Right. I'm would like these applications to run independently from one another. Of course this might not be really the proper way to do this, so totally open to criticism there.

Comment: ive been doing this with node a lot, but I always have the node app serve the react app statically.

Comment: The first version of this project was pure Flask and React came late to the game. Ended up having a huge mess on my hands so did an entire rewrite. Now there is a very clean separation, so simply allowing flask to route to the bundled React app may be the proper way to handle this while they both continue to live on the same server, and I totally accept that. Just need some people to bounce this off of at this point :)