# react-router-dom not rendering component but it changes url, how do I make it render without reloading?

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-router-dom

react-router-dom not rendering component but it changes url, how do I make it render without reloading?

I'm having a big trouble with this problem, the code works with create-react-app but not with python flask server.

It doesn't work with BrowserRouter nor HashRouter.

My project is based from [this one.](https://github.com/bonniee/react-flask)

And the state in which is not working is [here.](https://github.com/guitartsword/CoCWarWeight/tree/c3349871d4be5d5c17fa2790381aa527a19e8aab) If you prefer to view to code at github, i suggest to start looking at the app.py, then the index.html in the templates folder, then the app.js and Hello.js in the js folder.

My app.py (Server)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
WSGI_APLLICATION = Flask(__name__)
WSGI_APLLICATION.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

@WSGI_APLLICATION.route('/<path>')
@WSGI_APLLICATION.route('/')
def hello_world(path=''):
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGI_APLLICATION.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8080)
```

Here is my app.js (just rendering `<Hello/>`)

```
import Hello from './Hello';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('reactEntry'));
```

Here is my Hello.js (react-router-dom)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
class Hello extends Component{
  render() {
    const Home = () => (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
    )
    const About = () => (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    )
    const Topics = () => (
      <div>
        <h1>Topics</h1>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
          <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}></Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

I think the problem is flask or maybe I don't understand how react-router-dom works.

EDIT:
I discovered the problem isn't in flask, becuase i used the same app.py with another `bundle.js` created by `npm run build` of `create-react-app`

EXTRA "QUESTION" (FOR BONUS POINTS)
I don't want to do that random stuff on the index.html because of bundle.js loading from cache and requesting it (Again, maybe it is flask or I don't understan how cache works). How do I make it do the request and not load from cache?

Comment: I haven't run the code but I think you have to define the components outside your class I don't think it is a good idea to use such approach. Did you get this from somewhere else?

Comment: You javascript code looks OK. Just copied and pasted it on codesandbox.io and it worked. But your flask route might be wrong. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30620788/4228942) out and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @norbertpy I already try that and same result, I don't really understand what flask is doing, but it works on reload, so flask is rendering the html, but if you run the code from flask, flask never receives the request until you reload