# Flask React Fullstack application routing issue

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, webpack

I have Frontend **React** and backend **Python** in **fullstack** app and used the **webpack** to bundle the react component.I have added the Navigation bar containing the tabs , where these tabs has the link to  respective component. This Navigation works fine on the page , but when i refresh the page(from browser refresh button), it goes to server and finds the respective action there, which is not(as Navigation tab has static pages). I want this refresh call to be handled through react route ,not through python. Is there any way ,we can handle this refresh call through react router or webpack config?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30620788/3745365

Comment: Indeed, use a catch-all route with `/<path:my_path>`.