# React route pass-through

Tags: flask, react-router, react-typescript

I have a React-Typescript UI running on top of a flask API. I'm using BrowserRouter for routing paths in the UI. For a couple routes I want the react app to just fall back to rendering raw HTML returned by the underlying flask app.  ie I don't want to map the route to an element, just fetch the route from the back-end.  Is there some way to tell the route to behave this way?

**Edit**: Here's a detailed outline of the issue:

The react app is a thin client over top of a flask app.  When requests come in the front door, the flask app either handles the request, or re-routes it to the react UI:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    if path.startswith("api/v0/"):
        abort(404)
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.is_active:
        return render_template("ui/index.html")
    elif current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template("inactive.html")
    else:
        return render_template("unauth.html")
```

The flask app has a /logout route, that unloads the current user and then redirects to the (flask-handled) / route, prompting unauth.html to load.  This works fine when I directly navigate to /logout.

The React UI has its own router for loading page elements.  Loading /ui/index.html launches the app, and it essentially defines its own namespace for rendering pages:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate replace to="/collections" />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="collections">
        <Route path=":collectionId" element={<CollectionDetail />} />
        <Route index element={<CollectionsList />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="users">
        <Route index element={<UserList />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="images/:imageId" element={<ImageDetail />} />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={
        <main>
          <p>Page not found</p>
        </main>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
```

The issue is I have no way to break out of the react app context once I'm in it. Specifically, placing a `<Link />` to "/logout" takes the default route in the app and renders "Page not found".  But if I navigate directly to /logout the flask app handles it correctly.

One solution might be to move all the html-generating flask responses to the react app, but I think this would complicate routing in the flask app itself- ideally flask is only aware of the single entry point to the react app at /ui/index.html

Comment: You can't do this via the `Route` component. `react-router` only concerns itself with defined routes to handle and navigate to within your React app. Can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] for what "fetching routes from the backen" would look like?

Comment: My question is similar to this one, but I want to go in the other direction: escape from the react context and force flask to handle the request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620276/flask-and-react-routing

Comment: Which are the routes, or what are the links used, that you want the backend to handle?

Comment: I specifically want the backend to handle /logout.  Also, once unauthenticated, the flask back-end has a static login page. I'll edit above to express the full index() definition- I initially simplified it to keep it small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Link` component has a `reloadDocument` prop that can be used to "skip client side routing and let the browser handle the transition normally (as if it were an `<a href>`)". In doing so this a page request is made to the server and can be handled there.

See [Link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link).

> ```
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   to: To;
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Example:

```
<Link to="/logout" reloadDocument>Logout</Link>
```